# nsurlrequest wont load the pdf

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlrequest

```
NSString* urlText = @"http://www2.htk.dk/Socialpsykiatrien/menuplan%20værestedet.pdf";
NSString* urlTextEscaped = [urlText stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlTextEscaped];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

here's my code. and it stops at NSURLRequest each time... it looks like it loads the url correctly tho
but i can't seem to find the error

all the console says is : (lldb)

Comment: You are adding escape encoding to an already escaped url it seems you already have %20 in the urlText.

Comment: i also have a æ in the link...

Comment: tried this aswelll
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www2.htk.dk/Socialpsykiatrien/menuplan%20værestedet.pdf"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL]; and it loads nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine if you avoid percent escaping something that is already percent escaped:

```
NSString* urlText = @"http://www2.htk.dk/Socialpsykiatrien/menuplan værestedet.pdf";
NSString* urlTextEscaped = [urlText stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlTextEscaped];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Or, if your source for this string already has a `%20` buried in it, you can unescape it and re-escape it:

```
NSString* urlText = @"http://www2.htk.dk/Socialpsykiatrien/menuplan%20værestedet.pdf";
NSString* urlTextUnescaped = [urlText stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSString* urlTextEscaped = [urlTextUnescaped stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlTextEscaped];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Comment: 2nd one worked like a charm. the source allrdy has the %20 sign incoded